# Combining two SQL Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

so im not great at sql so im a tad stuck on this issue:
I query our database and it returns a list of everything in it

```
SELECT Id, Version, Name, ImplementationId, ManagedDataRepoId, Description, ParentId FROM Entity
```

which returns for example:
317, 0, amAsset, **42**, 82, null, null.

The ImplementationId values are all ints which are in another table linked to the names of each item which i can retrive using:

```
SELECT i.Name from Implementation i
JOIN Entity e
ON e.ImplementationId = i.Id
```

which would return '**Current**' which is the name of ImplementationId 42 from the first query.

Is there any way to combine these into a single query? ideally so it would return:

317, 0, amAsset, **Current**, 82, null, null

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already got the join in the second query; all you have to do is select the actual columns you want.

```
SELECT e.Id, e.Version, e.Name, i.Name AS ImplementationId, e.ManagedDataRepoId, e.Description, e.ParentId
FROM Implementation i
     JOIN Entity e
         ON e.ImplementationId = i.Id
```

Comment: Perfect! Thats exactly what i needed. Is there any way to have it still refer to the result as 'ImplementationId' rather then calling it 'Name' now? The results are parsed to JSON and then fed into a DataTables display so its expecting the column headers to be maintained

Comment: @user2069834: There are several ways to rename a column, but I've included one above.  These are pretty basic SQL questions; I would recommend doing some reading on SQL querying.

Comment: thank you! Yea SQL is not usually something i work with but this project required a little bit of it, i was able to get almost everything but this bit. :) Thanks so much!

Comment: is it possible then to further do it with the ManagedDataRepoID column? getting that ID's name from another table called ManagedDataRepo?

Comment: @user2069834:  You can join on as many tables as you want and continue the same pattern.  Just add another `JOIN ... ON` and use the table in your columns list.

Comment: ok cool thanks :) i have next to 0 exp with SQL before this so sorta winging it based on what i can find on google :)

Answer (score 2):

to be safe, use the table alias for each column

```
SELECT e.Id, e.Version, e.Name,i.Name, e.ManagedDataRepoId, e.Description, e.ParentId from Implementation i
JOIN Entity e
ON e.ImplementationId = i.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

... to make things pretty (and more readable) you could lay it out in a more standard manner;

```
SELECT e.Id, 
       e.Version, 
       e.Name,
       i.Name, 
       e.ManagedDataRepoId, 
       e.Description, 
       e.ParentId 
FROM   Implementation i
       INNER JOIN Entity e
        ON e.ImplementationId = i.Id
```